# What permissions are required to access Crypto API?

Tags: java, windows, cryptoapi

An Oracle JRE 1.7 running on Win2008R2 is using the internal random seed generator (slow) instead of using the faster native generator.

After enabling a level of debugging, we can see the following error on stderr:

```
provider: Failed to use operating system seed generator: java.io.IOException: Required native CryptoAPI features not available on this machine
```

My suspicion is that the windows account executing the JVM is missing some sort of privilege. The account is not part of the guests or domain guests group, which would cause the above error to occur.

Does anybody know which permissions are required in order for a windows account being able to use the Crypto API?

I can't see any errors in the security event log (… default logging settings).